# Visual Studio C# debugger - the breakpoint will not currently be hit

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I know that this question has been asked several times, and many people here have suggested different answers. Though none of them are working for me.

I created a Windows Forms application with Visual Studio and .NET framework 4.0 and added a breakpoint. However, when I debug the application, an exclamation mark appears on the breakpoint and it says..

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation or compiler optimizations.

I have tried out several suggested solutions

- Cleaned the project
- Deleted the pdb
- Checked the configuration and ensured that it is debug
- Set the debug configuration from "x86" to "Any CPU"
- Tried creating project from scratch
- Tried re-installing .NET framework
- Removed temporary ASP.NET files

However, none of them seems to be working. I was able to debug my projects with breakpoints before and for some reason, something happened and I am not able to debug the projects any more. What should I look out for or fix to resolve this issue?

Comment: Set a break point on a line _before_ the one you are having trouble with and single step the code. You should then be able to see why/if the code is executed. I could just be the compiler optimised away the code; post the code in question.

Answer (score 5):

Probably your breakpoint is in a project which is not dependent on the "startup project". Implicitly these projects are not compiled on Run (button <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Go to: menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Project and Solutions* → *Build and Run* → uncheck first check box (**only build startup projects and dependencies on Run**).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio go to the menubar, menu *Debug* → *Windows* → *Modules*, find the assembly your code is located in and check the Symbol state. Chances are you're having Visual Studio loading a different version not matching your PDB files.

Comment: Checked it, it is loading correct pdb as well as correct executable. Further, It is not working even if I create a new project and run it without making any changes.

Comment: I assume you´re talking about an asp.net application, what happens if you dont start debugging, but attach to the already running application (IIS/Cassini)?

Comment: I've clearly specified that it is windows forms application (i.e. desktop application). However, I also tried out your suggestion and the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and it stumped me for a while.  Ends up I had inadvertently switched my build configuration away from DEBUG to another configuration that was more optimized and did not "Define DEBUG constant": Project > Properties > Build > (first check box).

This may also happen if other projects in your solution are set to configurations other than DEBUG, usually accidentally, in the Solution Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here...

I was using Visual Studio 2005 - Professional Edition, and my problem was when I tried to breakpoint a Windows Forms application.

I've searched in many forums on the Internet, and I hadn't found any answer.
But the solution for this problem was easier than I had expected. Just right click on a Visual Studio shortcut (or .exe) and unmark *execute in compatibility mode*.

Answer (score -7):

Your best option is to create a new project. Then import all the files in the previous project, including your forms if any.

You are now set to OK to continue.

Comment: I have already stated that I have tried creating project from scratch, hope you have properly read the question